# Font-awesome responsive size with tailwindcss

Tags: font-awesome, tailwind-css

I would like to make the font size responsive, but It doesn't work with font-awesome.

How can I make the `xl:fa-3x` work on tailwindcss?

```html
<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-lg xl:fa-3x"></i>
```

Thank you

Comment: If you want to use predefined classes, I assume you should use classes related to font-size like `text-*`.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to apply that without removing fa-lg and that didn't work.

Comment: See. you can control size of fa icons by classes related to font size.

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution, You need to use tailwindcss [responsive design](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) mix with tailwindcss [font size](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size) like this: `md:text-6xl`, remember to hook up correctly to Your project `fontawesome` and `tailwindcss` good luck ;-)

Example code snippet:

```
<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt text-xs text-black sm:text-3xl md:text-6xl"></i>
```

---

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>

<body class="h-full">
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt text-xs text-black sm:text-3xl md:text-6xl mr-5"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-font-awesome-flag text-xs text-black sm:text-3xl md:text-6xl"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```